# Not sure why I am getting this "cannot find symbol" error

Tags: java, list, compiler-errors, symbols

I am getting a cannot find symbol error that doesn't come up when I use a very similar program.

> ```
> DeckDao.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
>    public List<Deck> loadDeck();
>                ^
>   symbol:   class Deck
>   location: interface DeckDao
> 1 error
> ```

here is my interface, where it can't find the symbol

```
package dao;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.List;


public interface DeckDao {  
   public List<Deck> loadDeck();
   public void saveDeck();
   }
```

edit: here is my Deck class

```
public class Deck {

   private String suit;
   private String rank;

   Deck(String suit, String rank){
      this.suit = suit;
      this.rank = rank;
   }


   public String getSuit() {
      return suit;
   }
   public void setSuit(String id) {
      this.suit = suit;
   }
   public String getRank() {
      return rank;
   }
   public void setRank(String rank) {
      this.rank = rank;
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a class called Deck in the same package?

Comment: I can edit and add my Deck class

Comment: Your Deck class doesn't seem to have a package statement. either add a package statement to set it in the same package, or import it in your PackageDao class

Answer (score 0):

From the error it seems as though `Deck` isn't recognized. It probably comes from another package, and you need to import it. E.g.:

```
import mypackage.Deck;
```